# Google map not working after publishing app on play store

Tags: google-maps, debugging, google-play, release

I published app three days before, The map was working before, but now map stopped working. I added the SHA1 key in the google console. Do I need to create 2 different API key for debug and release?

Now while I am checking the un-signed app, the map is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need another API key for your release build if you want to restrict it (which is strongly recommended), because you'll need to get the SHA-1 fingerprint for your release certificate. The debug one won't work.

You can follow the instructions from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#fingerprint).

Also make sure that your API key is set in your google_maps_api.xml file within your release folder and in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Hope this helps.